# React-Native icon at the right side of TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**What am I trying to achieve**

I am currently facing a styling issue at the TextInput from react-native.
What I am trying to achieve is to display an icon within the TextInput.

**Current situation**

Creating a TextInput with the following code.

```
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder={translationStrings.searchPlaceHolder}
                            style={styles.searchStyling}
                        />
```

This looks like below:

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlTga.jpg)

What am I trying to achieve:

[Wished situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJcl6.jpg)

Does someone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how ive achieved it

```
searchBar = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection:'row' , alignItems:'center'}}>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Search your issues                                      "
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps
          onChangeText={text => this.props.chnageInputText(text.toLowerCase())}
        />
        <Image
          style={faqStyles.imT}
          source={require('../assets/images/maglass1.png')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

This is how ive made a custom searchbar by wrapping an image and textInput in a View >ill always prefer using custom made components rather than libraries external. Try this and hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Please see the below image, this is what ive achieved. ive reversed the elemnts like text input and magnifying glass image for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  import {Item,Input} from 'native-base'

  <Item>
  <Input>
  </Input>
  <TouchableOpacity>
  <Icon></Icon>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </Item>
```

using native-base use input instead of textInput.

Otherwise just use a view with flexDirection:'row'